# Norm of the Resolvent

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\mathbb{H}$ be a Hilbert space, $A$ a self-adjoint operator with domain $D_{A}$, $R_{A}$ the resolvent of $A$, and $z$ a point in the resolvent set $\rho(A)$. How could you prove the inequality
\begin{equation}
||R_{A}(z)|| \leq 1/ d(z,\sigma(A)),
\end{equation}
where $\sigma(A)$ is the spectrum of $A$, and $d(z,\sigma(A))$ the distance of $z$ from $\sigma(A)$?
I found this inequality in [Hislop & Sigal, Introduction to Spectral Theory](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0741-2), Sect 5.2, where they reference Reed and Simon, Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics, vol. I, but I could not find a proof in that book.
Thank you very much in advance.

PS I just note here that since for any closed operator
\begin{equation}
||R_{A}(z)|| \geq 1/ d(z,\sigma(A)),
\end{equation}
(just note that all the point $w$ such that $|z-w| < ||R_{A}(z)||$ belong to $\rho(A)$), the above inequality must actually hold with equality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a bounded normal operator $N$, the norm and spectral radius of $N$ are the same. That is, $\|N\|=\sup_{\lambda\in\sigma(N)}|\lambda|$.

Let $\lambda \notin \sigma(A)$. Assume $A$ is unbounded. Then $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is bounded and normal, with
$$
         \sigma((A-\lambda I)^{-1})=\frac{1}{\sigma(A)-\lambda}\cup\{0\}=\left\{ \frac{1}{\mu-\lambda} : \mu\in\sigma(A) \right\}\cup\{0\}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
     \|(A-\lambda I)^{-1}\|=\sup_{\xi\in\sigma((A-\lambda I)^{-1})}|\xi|
   = \sup_{\mu\in\sigma(A)}\frac{1}{|\mu-\lambda|} = \frac{1}{\mbox{dist}(\lambda,\sigma(A))}.
$$

Comment: It looks much more simple than I could ever imagine! I have only a doubt about the first line. I only know that $\mu \in \mathbb{C}$ belongs to $\sigma(A)$ if and only if $(\mu - \lambda)^{-1}$ belongs to $\sigma(R_{A}(\lambda))$. But still $\sigma(R_{A}(\lambda))$ could contain zero. Or am I wrong? This in any case shouldn't change the proof. Thank you very much for your invaluable help.

Comment: The result I quoted in my previous comment is from Schmudgen, Unbounded Self-Adjoint Operators on Hilbert Space, Proposition (2.10).

Comment: @MauryBarbato : If $A$ is unbounded, then $0$ is in the spectrum of $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$, which is the only possible point being left out of $\frac{1}{\sigma(A)-\lambda}$, but $0$ is in the closure of the set $\frac{1}{\sigma(A)-\lambda}$ if $A$ is unbounded. I invoked closure to avoid a lengthy discussion of that one point $0$.

Comment: @MauryBarbato : Actually I think you have equality of the closure and the spectrum, which also gives equality for the norm in the final line. So that point was worth you mentioning it. I changed everything to equality (both of spectrum and of norm.)

Comment: If $A$ is bounded, then $0$ is not in $\sigma(R_{A}(\lambda))$, and since $\sigma(R_{A}(\lambda))$ is closed, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $0$ such that $\sigma(R_{A}(\lambda)) \cap V = \emptyset$. Consider now $A$ undbounded. Then $0$ is in $\sigma(R_{A}(\lambda))$. So to conclude that $\sigma(R_{A}(\lambda)) = \text{closure} \left( \frac{1}{\sigma(A) - \lambda} \right)$, it is enough to show that if $A$ is unbounded, then $0$ is not an isolated point of $\sigma(R_{A}(\lambda))$, as you claim. Could you give a proof or a reference for this statement? Thank you very much.

Comment: @MauryBarbato : If $A$ is unbounded, then $R_A(\lambda)$ cannot have a bounded everywhere-defined inverse, because that bounded inverse would be $A-\lambda I$, which means $0\in\sigma(R_A(\lambda))$. Conversely, if $A$ is bounded, then $R_A(\lambda)$ has a bounded inverse--namely, $A-\lambda I$, which means $0\notin\sigma(R_A(\lambda))$.

Comment: @MauryBarbato : For the interesting piece:  If a normal operator $N$ has bounded spectrum, then $N=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=R}\lambda\frac{1}{\lambda I-N}d\lambda$, where $|z|=R$ encloses the spectrum of $N$, which is a bounded operator.

Comment: Yes, but to prove that $\sigma(R_{A}(\lambda)) = \text{closure} \left( \frac{1}{\sigma(A) - \lambda} \right)$, we should show that if $A$ id unbounded, then $0$ is not an isolated point of $\sigma(R_{A}(\lambda))$, otherwise $0 \in \sigma(R_{A}(\lambda))$, but $0$ would not belong to $\text{closure} \left( \frac{1}{\sigma(A) - \lambda} \right)$.

Comment: @MauryBarbato : That's where the second comment comes in to play using the contour integral.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen the second comment. Could you give some more detail or some reference, please? Why does $N$ admit such an integral representation? And why this representation implies that $N$ is bounded?

Comment: Since this discussion has its own interest, but is not related directly to the original question, if you agree, I will post a new question, so that you can summarize the steps to prove that $\sigma(R_{A}(\lambda)) = \text{closure} \left( \frac{1}{\sigma(A) - \lambda} \right)$.

Comment: @MauryBarbato : In the meantime, I've replaced with = for the subsets with $\subseteq$ and replaced equality for the norm with $\le$, which is what I originally had. This is then a solution of your problem.

Comment: @MauryBarbato : By the way, I get equality without knowing the closure property. You can check for yourself in the modified answer.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts: Do you know how much this extends to nonlinear problems? For instance, is there an analogue for:
$$ \sigma ((A-\lambda I)^{-1}) = \frac{1}{\sigma(A-\lambda)} \cup \{0\}?$$
e.g.
$$ \sigma((A - B\lambda - \lambda^2)^{-1})=???$$