# Norm of resolvent goes to infinity

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

**How to prove this problem?**

Let X be a non-zero Banach space and $T \in \mathcal{L}(X).$ Let $\rho(T)$ be the resolvent set, $\sigma(T)$ the spectrum of T. Suppose $\{\lambda_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subset \rho(T)$ and $\lambda \in \sigma(T)$ such that $\lambda_n \rightarrow \lambda.$ Prove that $\sup_n\|(\lambda_nI - T)^{-1}\|_{\mathcal{L}(X)} = \infty.$

I have tried to use this [Norm of the Resolvent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1855151/norm-of-the-resolvent) but operator is not self-adjoint.
**

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: In  the reference you mentioned,  the lower bound of the norm of the resolvent is true for  Banach spaces. Namely $\|\mu I-T)^{-1}\|\ge {1\over d},$ where $d$ denotes the distance from $\mu$ to $\sigma(T).$ In this way $\|(\lambda_nI-T)^{-1}\|\ge |\lambda_n-\lambda|^{-1}.$

Comment: In the reference it is said that this can be shown using Neumann series, but I don't see how. Do you have any insight? @BazyliZuczek

Comment: $$(\lambda_n I -T)^{-1}(\lambda I - T)= I -(\lambda_n-\lambda )(\lambda  I-T)^{-1}.$$  The left hand side represents a nonivertible operator. The right hand side would be invertible if $\|(\lambda_n I -T)^{-1}\|<|\lambda_n-\lambda|^{-1}.$ Therefore the opposite inequality holds i.e. $\|(\lambda_n I -T)^{-1}\|\ge |\lambda_n-\lambda|^{-1}.$

Comment: How did you get the identity? The right side has $(\lambda I - T)^{-1}$, but $\lambda I - T$ is not invertible. @BazyliZuczek

Comment: There was is a misprint, sorry. $$(\lambda_n I -T)^{-1}(\lambda I -T)= I -(\lambda_n-\lambda) (\lambda_n I -T)^{-1}$$